# How to connect Java with MongoDB in Windows Azure's worker role?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, azure-worker-roles, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring RESTFul web service project that use "Spring Data MongoDB" library to connect with MongoDB database.

After successfully testing with my local machine, I am ready to deploy on cloud server (Windows Azure's worker role).

I have followed step-by-step from official website ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure/#deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure)) with additional worker role called TomcatWorkerRole (since I want to run mongodb for internal use only, I have to deploy my web application in the same cloud service).

Everything works fine in deployment but in setting the database connection of my application is not like that.

The problem is because the replica-set is look like this ..

```
rs:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
   "_id" : "rs",
   "version" : 1,
   "members" : [
         {
             "_id" : 0,
             "host" : "rs_0:27017"
         },
         {
             "_id" : 1,
             "host" : "rs_1:27017"
         },
         {
             "_id" : 2,
             "host" : "rs_2:27017"
         }
   ]
}
```

Due to the description ..

> To account for possible changes in the IPs of the instances running
>   MongoDB, the worker role uses the hosts file to alias each of the
>   instances. Hence the client application instance needs the same
>   instances. Additionally the client application must also have the name
>   of the replica set.

The problem is how can I know "rs_X" stand to which host ?
Because I have to specify the host in order to create the client connection.

Could anyone help me, please ? Do I have to change my mind to use VM's role for MongoDB instead of worker role ?

Thank you.

PS. Sorry for my english.